# How to increase data storage in salesforce developer edition?

Tags: data-storage

I need 1 GB storage for records, 5 GB storage for file (Data Storage = 1 GB, File Storage = 5 GB). I am using Developer edition. Can you please suggest me a great app which can provide me 1 Gb DataStorage & 5Gb FileStorage?
How to buy additional storage from Salesforce? I am trying to contact Accounting rep, but failed to login to Power of US hub as it says my Salesforce Developer edition is not registered, & there is no signup button. I can’t free up spaces by deleting any object or anything from my SF org.

These apps seems good, but only for FILE STORAGE.
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IzEDEA0
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000008amNrEAI (review is not good)

Answer (score 2):

Developer Edition orgs are meant for development of new code to put into packages and install into customer production accounts.  They cannot be upgraded into Active orgs, which have different storage limits and the ability to add more.

If this is for business use, I recommend signing up for a Lightning Professional sales cloud trial here:
https://www.salesforce.com/editions-pricing/sales-cloud/

They come with 1Gb data storage and I believe 5Gb file storage as well.  Trials expire after 30 days, at which point you can purchase a license.

Comment: So, for SF developer edition, I can't get 1GB data storage?

Comment: @tanmoy John answered it pretty well. Developer orgs are designed to give you full functionality whilst being limited enough that you'd need to fork out £££ to really use it. Salesforce aren't daft! ;)